# Passing comma separated list from controller to model

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I am using Codeigniter and trying to pass a comma separated list from my controller to the model to use it in a `where_not_in` query. I have the following code to create the comma separated list.

```
$mnames = Array();
foreach($facet_group['manufacturer_name'] as $u) $mnames[] = $u['value'];
$manufacturer_list = implode(",",$mnames);
```

which produces the following: Alcatel,Apple,Huawei,LG,Microsoft,Motorola,Nokia,Samsung,Sony. My query is this:

```
$this->db->select('name');
$this->db->from('wl_manufacturers');
$this->db->where('active', 1);
$this->db->where('supplier_type', 'product');
$this->db->where_not_in('name', $str);
```

$str being the comma separated list

the output from profiler is:

```
SELECT `name`
FROM `wl_manufacturers`
WHERE `active` = 1
AND `supplier_type` = 'product'
AND `name` NOT IN('Alcatel,Apple,Huawei,LG,Microsoft,Motorola,Nokia,Samsung,Sony')
```

This doesn't seem to work because there is no single quotes around each item in the list.  However if I create the list manually like this: $array = array('Alcatel','Apple','Huawei','LG','Microsoft','Motorola','Nokia','Samsung','Sony'). It works and the output from the profiler is:

```
SELECT `name`
FROM `wl_manufacturers`
WHERE `active` = 1
AND `supplier_type` = 'product'
AND `name` NOT IN('Alcatel', 'Apple', 'Huawei', 'LG', 'Microsoft', 'Motorola', 
'Nokia', 'Samsung', 'Sony')
```

I have tried adding single quotes to the comma separated list items before passing it to the model:

```
$str = "'" . implode ( "', '", $mnames ) . "'";
```

but the the profiler output is this:

```
SELECT `name`
FROM `wl_manufacturers`
WHERE `active` = 1
AND `supplier_type` = 'product'
AND `name` NOT IN('\'Alcatel\', \'Apple\', \'Huawei\', \'LG\', \'Microsoft\', 
\'Motorola\', \'Nokia\', \'Samsung\', \'Sony\'')
```

Again not working because backslashes have been added. So the question is how can I create a comma separated list, pass it through to my model and get the query to work correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to explode your comma separated string ($str) to create an array

```
$arr=explode (',',$str)
```

then you can use it in your query like

```
$this->db->where_not_in('name', $arr);
```

see [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php): 
and CI's [where_not_in()](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data)

Answer (score 0):

Seems that `$this->db->where_not_in` is expecting an array of values ... or, if a string is passed in, it the same as passing an array of one item, the string.

So, if you start with an array, just pass that into `where_not_in`.  But if you are starting with a string of CSV, then `str_getcsv(my_string_of_csv)` to get an array you can pass into `where_not_in`.

NOTE: You want to use `str_getcsv` and not just `explode` if your string of CSV might contain whitespace, escaped characters, and/or quoted values.  See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php